# Trigger AWS Lambda Function when Docker image pushed to ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ecs

I want to run security scans on docker images which are pushed to ECS. Can I trigger this somehow from CloudWatch Events, or is there another method?

Comment: you'll likely have to go via a cloudtrail audit trail: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/logging-using-cloudtrail.html

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]